# Porting an application from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows

I have one application, which has been developed on Linux (gcc based), I need to port the entire application to Windows.

Can you suggest me which tool/interface should choose to build the environment?

If I choose Visual Studio, will it support GCC compiler tool chain or which one is suitable among MinGW and Cygwin ?

Please give me some Inputs and the challenges will there while porting.

Thanks...

Comment: Please add the type of application (server, textmode interactive app, windowed app, ..), and whether it contains *nix specific calls like `fork`.  Sometimes porting is as simple as recompiling, but often it's a **lot** more than that...

Comment: It is stress tool and uses System calls and uses kernel API's as well.

Comment: The systemcalls may be the biggest challenges, some calls/concepts just don't exist under Windows and are pretty tough to emulate correctly.  A library like [APR](http://apr.apache.org/) may help to iron out some of the diffences but you won't find an all encompassing list of portability issues and their solution anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend an abstraction layer for all your OS-dependent routines. You then provide two implementations of those routines. One for Linux, one for Windows, and you compile one or the other depending on the current platform. You should keep the portable code well separated from the platform-specific code.

Of course you could also use an already existing platform abstraction layer, like Qt's [Core](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtcore-index.html) module (which provides abstractions for threading and I/O) or the [Network](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html) module, which provides portable networking. Of course I cannot determine whether this is suitable in your case or not, since I don't know what kinds of system calls you need or if C++ is even acceptable, but it might be worth looking into it (or other similar portability libraries.)

As a compiler, you can actually build the Windows binaries under Linux. I've been doing that for a long time now, since I'm not a Visual Studio kind of guy. I prefer the likes of CMake or Autotools.  For that, I recommend [MXE](http://mxe.cc).

Comment: Can you suggest me Linux to Windows porting library (which already exists)

Answer (score -1):

Well, GCC is just the copiler.  I assume they are just c or cpp files so just compile them in windows with a windows compatible c/cpp compiler.